# Ruby https get call is stuck

Tags: ruby, https, connection

I have this snippet of code:

```
def httpsGet url
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    http.use_ssl = true
    request.initialize_http_header({"someHeader" => "82739840273985734"})
    http.request(request)
end
```

i've been running a script that uses this just fine for the past week. the script basically calls out to some 3rd party service with different parameters many many times over and over again. suddenly, yesterday and today, this method seems to be hanging sometimes (i stuck `puts` in several places). it is annoying because this method sometimes hangs after 100 calls, sometimes 20 calls, sometimes many hours later...etc.

1. is that code not the best way to make an https call with headers in Ruby?
2. how do i debug this to ensure i'm not doing something wrong?
3. is the 3rd party service down? but even if so, shouldn't the connection in ruby time out? (like i get a timeout exception) ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `open_timeout` and `ssl_timeout` timeout [defined for this library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html):

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.open_timeout = 5 #  create connection timeout after 5 seconds
http.ssl_timeout = 5  # read timeout after 5 seconds
```